# How to pass data from HTML Form to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS?

Tags: php

I am trying to pass newsletter subscribe information (name and email) from an HTML Form to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.

My form looks like this:

```
    <form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="URL_TO_POST_TO">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" autofocus="" required="" placeholder="Email address">
    <input class="form-control" type="name" required="" placeholder="name">
    <label class="checkbox">

    </label>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
    </form>
```

My PHP Curl looks like:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();


$EMAIL = "Test";

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => 
"https://spaces.nexudus.com/api/content/newslettersubscribers",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '{\n\"BusinessId\": 469969507}", \n\"Name\",'. 
$EMAIL .',\n\\"Email\\": \\'.$EMAIL.'\\"\n"}',
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: Bearer 
123345345345345345345345345345345",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Content-Type: application/json",

),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
echo $response;
}
```

?>
I was thinking there might be a way to pass my form into the $EMAIL variable.

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add n action to your form:

```
<form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="path/to/file.php">
```

Add a "name" attribute to your input:

```
<input name="email" class="form-control" type="text" autofocus="" required="" placeholder="Email address">
```

And then, after submit, get on the server (PHP) side:

```
$EMAIL = $_POST['email'];
```

Comment: Thank you, worked great. Any chance you know how to run file.php without outputting contents to screen?

Comment: remove this line: `echo $response;`